# How can I embed a Perl interpreter in my C# program using Mono on Linux?

Tags: c#, perl, mono, embed

Does anyone know if it's possible to call a Perl sub from Mono in C#?  This is on a Linux machine.

Maybe `DllImport`?  We want to avoid loading perl every time if possible, as well.

Comment: I also want to avoid merely running perl via Process.Start.  I think it would be difficult to call subs that return arrays or hashes in that manner.  The sub I'm wishing to call is specific to an existing system and returns SQL results in multi-dimensional arrays/hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interop works fine with Mono under Linux to call C-Code.
Thus I would consider that you look at [perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html).
Instead of a C-program you need to create a shared C-library. 
For Interop there are several good guides - a potential pitfall are sizes of datatypes, because you get really plaform/CPU dependent.
Let me know if you need anywhere more detailed information.

Comment: This will definitely get me rolling.  I will probably post back if are any pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

[This thread on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=530344) might help.

Comment: This post suggests they haven't tried it on Linux, has anyone tried it?  I am wondering if the Microsoft COM object they use in the example even works on Linux.

We will try it, just wondering if anyone has already.

Comment: @Jonathan the COM object does not even exist on Linux. You did not mention Linux in your question. Maybe you should update to clarify.

Comment: I was expect the mention of Mono would make one assume I'm referring to Linux.

Comment: @Jonathan Why??? http://mono-project.com/skins/Mono2/images/home-download-mono.png

Comment: Which OS is listed first on your pic?  If I were a betting man, and someone mentioned mono.  I would bet they were running it on Linux.  Why run Mono on Windows when the .Net framework is fully available?

Comment: Mono is available on all three platforms. I work mostly on Windows and I am using Mono to learn C#. Your expectation that the mention of Mono should imply that you are on Linux is similar to an assumption that the mention of `gcc` should imply Linux. Neither is warranted. This, of course, is not a big deal, but methinks you are being a little too persistent with this.