# Parse::RecDescent Module in Perl

Tags: c#, perl, nlp, recursive-descent

I found that [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parse%3a%3aRecDescent) is a Perl module to implement natural language parser. Is there any way to implement Parse::RecDescent in C# language also?

Comment: How do you implement a natural language parser with `P::RD`?

Comment: P:RD is a Top Down Parser and i am trying to use it in my Language translation Project

Comment: You might want to take a look at Marpa as well. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Marpa

Answer (score 2):

Instead of implementing `P::RD` in C# maybe it's better to embed perl interpreter into your C# application? [How can I embed a Perl interpreter in my C# program using Mono on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119923/how-can-i-embed-a-perl-interpreter-in-my-c-sharp-program-using-mono-on-linux) might help a bit.